# Is there a way to keep a WinSCP session open within a main form and access that same session from another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winscp, winscp-net

I need to be able to open a WinSCP session from the main form of the application, keep that session open, and access that same session from different application forms at different times. This is in the interest of saving time opening and closing sessions.

Is this possible? I'm not sure what more info needs to be provided to help in the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That helped, but maybe I can add some more information to help with the issue I am having.

I need to keep the session in the same form (let's call it ftpForm), so... I load the session (let's call it mainSession) when the form opens. The user can open another form and then come back to the ftpForm. This reinitializes the form.

How do I check to see if mainSession is still active without doing "using (Session mainSession = new Session())" again?

Comment: Just getting back to this project after being called off for a while... Can you please provide an example?  I'm not really following that. And thanks for the replies.

Comment: The only examples I have that tend to make sense to me are from the WinSCP library. But I cannot figure out how to open a WinSCP session from one method and call that open session from another method.
For example, a method named OpenMainSession() which does exactly that, and RemoveFiles() which references the already open session.
I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Perfect!  thank you!

Comment: Yes. that gave me the information I needed to understand the concept and get it done. Thanks again.